# Como colocar jogo da forca em uma janela, para poder enviar para alguem jogar

Tags: python-requests

Gostaria de fazer esse jogo da forca funcionar em uma janela, gostaria de fazer de um modo que minha filha possa jogar, estou aprendendo ainda, segue o código:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

largura = 640
altura = 640

tela = pygame.display.set_mode((largura,altura))

pygame.display.set_caption("Jogo da Lala")

def draw():
          display.fill([19, 173, 235])

while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
        pygame.display.update()


import emoji

print(emoji.emojize(':girl: Joguinho da Larissa :girl:'))

print('\n')
print('Oi meu nome é Larissa, mas todo mundo me chama de "LALA".')

while True:

    resp = input(emoji.emojize('Vamos brincar de forca? :skull:'))
    if resp == 'yes' or resp == 'sim' or resp == 'y' or resp == 's':
        print('Que legal, então vamos começar!')
        break

    if resp == 'não' or resp == 'no' or resp == 'n':
        print(emoji.emojize('Que pena! :sob:'))

import sys

import random


def run():
    print("Digite uma letra:")

    wordbank = ["casa", "abacate", "amor", "tatiane", "walles", "larissa", "familia", "lilica", "cachorro", "gato",
                "bicicleta", "televisao", "violao", "samuel", "vovo", "ian", "sol", "dia", "chocolate", "boneca",
                "carro", "luluca", "aviao", "telefone", "celular", "dormir", "estudar"]

    word = random.choice(wordbank)

    guesses = " "

    turns = 10

    while turns > 0:

        failed = 0

        for char in word:

            if char in guesses:

                print(char)

            else:

                print("_")

                failed += 1

        if failed == 0:

            print("Você venceu!!! Parabéns")

            choice = input("Quer jogar novamente y/n\n")

            if "y" or "s" or "sim" in choice:

                run()

            elif "n" or "nao" in choice:

                sys.exit()

            else:

                print("Deu algo errado, digite s or n.")

        guess = input("Digite uma letra:")

        guesses += guess

        if guess not in word:

            turns -= 1

            print("Errou!")

            print(f"Você tem mais {turns} tentativas.")

            if turns == 0:

                print("Você perdeu!")

                choice = input("Quer jogar novamente s/n\n")

                if "y" or "s" in choice:

                    run()

                elif "n" in choice:

                    sys.exit()

                else:

                    print("Deu algo errado, digite s or n.")


run()
```

Comment: Onde ela vai jogar esse jogo, num PC com Windows/Linux/MacOs, Celular/Tablet Android/IOS

Comment: seria legal se fosse pelo telefone, android

Comment: Veja se o ajuda https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/ é a documentação do [Python for Android](https://pypi.org/project/python-for-android/0.4/).

Comment: vou olhar, obrigado